# "Emergency Stop" when building simple qtree

Tags: errors, tikz-qtree

Latex fails building the following code with error "Emergency stop."

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \Tree  
    [.a
        [.b 
            [.c
                [.d
                    [.e
                        [.f]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

After removing the ".f" child, it compiles fine. Is there some limitation to qtree I have reached?

Comment: `\end{tikzpicture}` is missing.

Comment: Ah yeah. Some sort of Copy&Paste error. If fixed it and updated the question. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Try `[.f ]` instead of `[.f]`...

Comment: Yep, that fixed it. Form an answer and I'll accept it ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `qtree` (and `tikz-qtree`), *tree labels are delimited by whitespace* ([p.5, `qtree` documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/qtree/qtreenotes.pdf#page=5)). So, in your example, use `[.f ]` instead of `[.f]`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \Tree  
    [.a
        [.b 
            [.c
                [.d
                    [.e
                        [.f ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```